# Enabling scroll on UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have created a UIScrollView in a ContainerView and a UITextView as a subview of UIScrollView. I initialize the textView with scrollEnabled set to true. Now based on the contentOffset.y of the scrollView, I want to keep toggling scrollEnabled on the textView. But for some reason, once I set scrollEnabled to false, I can't seem to enable scroll again...

```
override func viewDidload() {
    self.scrollView  = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(...))
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
    self.textView    = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(...))
    self.textView.scrollEnabled = true
    self.textView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.scrollView.addSubview(self.textView)

}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   if self.scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 180 {
        self.textView.scrollEnabled  = true // This does not work!
     } else {
     self.textView.scrollEnabled  = false // This works!
     }
  }
```

Comment: If you disable the scrolling, the `contentOffset` cannot grow anymore, so the first condition can't be satisfied anymore. Why do you want to disable/enable the scrolling? Maybe there is another solution to your problem than this.

Comment: I am disabling scrolling on textView not scrollView. So contentOffset is not a problem...I have a menu(UIButtons) around half way down the screen. When user starts scrolling, user should be able to scroll menu to top and only then textView starts scrolling.

Comment: Could you add some logging in the `scrollViewDidScroll` method to see what the contentOffset is, if it ever gets to be 180? Or just add a breakpoint in the `if`, to see if the condition is ever satisfied. Maybe the `contentSize` of the scrollView is not bigger than 180?

Comment: It does get satisfied... But once i set textView.scrollEnabled to false, it just doesn't want to scroll again

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the same problem, and eventually dealt with it by subclassing UITextView as shown below:

```
class TextView: UITextView {

    var displayScrolling: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = displayScrolling
        }
    }

    override var contentOffset: CGPoint {
        set {
            if displayScrolling {
                super.contentOffset = newValue
            }
        }
        get {
            return super.contentOffset
        }
    }
}
```

At init (or in interface builder), set your instance of TextView to allow scrolling.  In order to **not** scroll, set the 'displayScrolling' var to false.  When you want to scroll, set 'displayScrolling' to true.

Answer (score -3):

It will be scroll enabled if the text is longer.

I wish you luck!